# Convert LINQ with Model To Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a LINQ to get the records in Personnel table that exist in Users table. Here's the tutorial I'm currently following: [Convert the Results of a LINQ Query to an Array](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/api/linq-guide/data-access-tasks-querying-model-convert-result-to-array).

However, when I try to implement it in my codes I'm having an error: `'UserModel[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<string>(IQueryable<string>, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>'`

```
var users = from u in db.USR_MSTR select new UserModel { emp_id = u.EMP_ID };

UserModel[] userList = users.ToArray();

var matches = from p in db.PERSONNEL_MSTR
            where userList.Contains(p.EMP_ID) //userList is generating the error above
            select p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Contains is awaiting for UserModel instance to be passed, that's why you get error. Just use .Any() instead:

```
var matches = from p in db.PERSONNEL_MSTR
            where userList.Any(u=> u.ID == p.EMP_ID)
            select p;
```

What it does here is: If p.EMP_ID is found inside userList, than it is selected.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, I like it how it's very simple. I'll try this too and will check with the other answer to see what's more convenient for my whole project.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you made a mistake in this

```
userList.Contains(p.EMP_ID)
```

userList is an **IQueryable<UserModel>** object, it not an **IQueryable<string>** array, on the other hand p.EMP_ID is a string, that the reason why you got that error.

You need to fix it as following

```
List<string> userIdList = users.Select(u => u.emp_id.ToString()).ToList();

var matches = from p in db.PERSONNEL_MSTR
        where userIdList.Contains(p.EMP_ID)
        select p;
```

Comment: Thanks man! I've implemented yours already, but haven't yet ran the program as I was still configuring some other items. Will let tag is as accepted once it executes succesfully

Comment: how do I put multiple columns to a `string[] userIdList`? Because I want some details in the `var users` to be shown also in `var matches`. I suppose I should change this code `users.Select(u => u.emp_id.ToString()).ToArray()` to include more than just the `emp_id` but not sure how